# Difficulties following a Django tutorial

Tags: python, django

Basically copied this tutorial

http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/examples/django-simple.html

Then I used `python manage.py runserver` to initiate the server (using cmd prompt in Win 8). Local server seems to set up just fine.

But once I try to load up the page, it throws up this error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named google.appengine.api
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named google.appengine.api
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\authomatic\providers\gaeopenid.py in <module>, line 29
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.7
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\darkace\\Documents\\2013 - 2014\\Python\\Django\\example',
 'C:\\windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 25 Aug 2014 20:14:34 +0100
```

Is the problem that the module is missing (if so which ones do I need?), or do I need to install/run app engine, or does my setup need to be different for windows?

Not really sure what I'm doing to be honest

Comment: Have you run `bootstrap.sh` ? Without any error ?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the tutorial where it calls appengine. Did you try to modify the code to use Google sign in? Or are you attempting to run this code in Google App Engine? Or something else?

Comment: @Dan From http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/development.html#development-environment-setup `authomatic` should install the AppEngine SDK as part of its setup. This is probably (maybe?) required by that software.

Comment: @Dan there's something included called gaeopenid. I think that's related to appengine?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I pip installed authomatic already. Unless you're suggesting I do something else with it?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux maybe I installed authomatic without all the dependencies? Should I be looking for a way to install the missing module? I'm using pip install on Windows

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell you much more. I do not know that software. All I know is that the "setup page" (see the link in my previous comment) specify running the `bootstrap.sh` script in order to install the required dependencies. That being said, as this is a `*.sh` file, this is most probable for Linux. Unless `cygwin` was required? No, really, I don't know... If I were you, maybe I would try a clean fresh install -- trying to notice if it downloads some dependencies as part of the `pip` installation. Or being vigilant to try to catch some fleeting error message...

Comment: hmm essentially it sounds easier if I just use linux in a Virtualbox or something. There's no bootstrap.sh (or similar) installed with authomatic and as you say that's a linux extension anyway.. Possibly there's something in defining authomatic to use gaeopenid? I'm pretty much new to all this so I don't know haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using [this provider](http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/reference/providers.html#google-app-engine-openid-providers), so you need install the [appengine SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=es), or change the [provider](http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/reference/providers.html#oauth2-providers).

In the django sample, the author refers the google provider in this line:

```
from authomatic.providers import oauth2, oauth1, openid, gaeopenid
```

remove the gaeopenid reference and will work